# 2 exact copies of autorun.inf, one works one doesnt

Tags: windows, usb, windows-10, filesystems, autorun

I have two Autorun.inf files, the code inside them are exact same.
But only 1 works, other one doesn't work.

The one that work is copied from DVD, and i edited it.
The one that doesn't work created on my desktop by renaming text file ( i correctly renamed it ).

This one works

[image]

This one doesn't work

[image]

If you want the files :

Working one : http://www16.zippyshare.com/v/64IutSu4/file.html

Not working one : http://www98.zippyshare.com/v/zEqU2BZ7/file.html

Does anyone know why doesn't the one i created on my desktop wont work?
and how can i get it working? and whats the difference between those 2 file?

Thanks.

Comment: I opened both with a hex editor and they are quite different when looking at the hex values. Its easy enough to make a new one. Make a Autorun text file and type in the data, save the file and change the extension from txt to inf.

Comment: @Moab That's what i did but i saved it as "UTF-8 with an UTF-8 BOM" - (dxiv) and that was the issue. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: I would dissagree in them beeing exact copies. This is simply impossible IF they are.

Comment: The first file says "usb". The second file says "usbk". Look at the last lines. Seems like a simple typo.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The 2nd `.inf`, which doesn't work, appears to have been saved as UTF-8 *with* a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

The UTF-8 BOM means that the file starts with the binary sequence `EF BB BF` (in hex). But Windows expects `autorun.inf` files to be plain text, so it won't recognize this one as such.

My advice is to choose the plain-text option in your text editor when saving `.inf` files or similar.

Comment: and this is why you do not use notepad for editing program files.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i dont think notepad adds BOM.

Comment: It doesn't, but it doesn't tell you about BOM either, and it will save it back in the same encoding as the original file.

Comment: UTF8 *is* plain text. I presume that you are talking about ASCII.

Comment: @fNek UTF-8 is a _variable-length_ (multi-byte) encoding. In this context, _plain text_ referred to a _single-byte_ encoding, commonly 7-bit ASCII. I guess 8-bit extended ASCII might be interpreted in the default Windows codepage and work, too, though I did not verify it and couldn't find it documented.

Comment: It's not even the variable-length encoding that is the problem. It's that the "BOM" (which isn't really a BOM at all, because a BOM is only used to distinguish little-endian from big-endian encodings of 16-bit or larger Unicode) is not visible inside the editor.  And the invisibility of the "BOM" is what makes it no longer plain text.

Comment: UTF-8 text is plain-tet, just like @fNek said. If you mean ASCII instead, say so.

Comment: @Deduplicator I did not mean that UTF-8 encoded text would _not_ be text. Of course it is. But, as I already clarified in my previous comment, in this context `plain text` referred to 7-bit ASCII or possibly 8-bit codepage encoding. While not rigorously precise, calling it `plain text` is rather common usage in Windows world. For example, if you run MS Word and Save-As a file, one format available is `plain text`, which defaults to the active ANSI codepage.

Comment: @dxiv: The default encoding for plain-text on windows is active ANSI codepage, and MS doesn't and won't support unicode as the ANSI-codepage, sure. But that doesn't change the fact that you can select UTF-8 without MS BOM there, and it's still plain-text.

Comment: The default encoding for INF files in Windows is UTF-16 (LE), MS explicitly prohibits ANSI and UTF-8: `INF files should be saved and encoded as Unicode (UTF-16); they must not be ANSI or UTF-8.` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/general-unicode-requirement `Microsoft uses UTF-16, little endian byte order.` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks

Answer (score 31):

As dxiv has said, this is caused by UTF-8 BOM.

The file editor you are using, Notepad++, can tell you the encoding of the file.

[image]

UTF-8 BOM adds header bytes to the file that breaks their compatibility with standard ASCII files, whereas UTF-8 without BOM (or just plain UTF-8) files are fully reverse compatible with standard ASCII file, assuming you do not use any UTF-8 characters.

Notepad++ also has a HEX editor plugin and you will be able to see these extra bytes with it:

[image]